# redirecting REST calls from apache to tomcat not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, mod-jk, ajp

I want apache to serve the static shtml(they also include other shtml files) pages and redirect the REST calls to tomcat.

To do this :

- I have made below entry in apache2.conf

  JkMount /* ajp13

  JkUnMount /myapp/ ajp13
- I have index.shtml in /my/deploment/dir/myapp
- I have site configuration in sites-enabled/mysite
- when I give the URL `http://localhost:80/myapp`, I can see index.shtml
- but if I give `http://localhost:80/myapp/myresources/testrs` ("testrs" is path to my default REST ws), this request is not redirected to tomcat and apache tries to serve it on its own and gives the 404(not found) error.

If I disable 'mysite', then,

- the `http://localhost:80/myapp/myresources/testrs` is redirected to tomcat
- but, `http://localhost:80/myapp` does not work.

Can somebody please let me know what setting am I missing here?